# How to get value of an input from a div parent via class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this script and its working perfectly but the problem is I have no control over the code structure as its dynamically generated.

I can easily get the value of the element (or whatever you call it e.g INPUT) but the problem is that the way I fetch the value

```
$('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev)
```

where the name="meal-356" is randomly generated and good thing that I can control the div parents class (not the ID) so I wonder if its possible to get the value of an element by class from its parent.

Like for example in order for me to get the value of input name="meal-356" I use this code

```
    $('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){

    if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
        var meal = 20;
    }
    else {
        var meal = 30;
    }

    $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

});
```

so instead of using

```
$('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev)
```

I'd like to use `$('.meal-wrapper')` so that any of the input, textarea or any form inside of that div will have the same effect

Here is my full script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
            var meal = 20;
        }
        else {
            var meal = 30;
        }

        $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:radio[name="drinks-123"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
            var drinks = 1;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
            var drinks = 1.20;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
            var drinks = 2;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
            var drinks = 1.75;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
            var drinks = 3;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
            var drinks = 1.25;
        }
        else {
            var drinks = 0;
        }

        $('#drinks').text((drinks).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });


    $('input:radio[name="extras-781"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
            var extras = 10;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
            var extras = 5;
        }
        else {
            var extras = 0;
        }
        $('#extras').text((extras).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });

    $('textarea[name="spoon-112"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var spoon = spoon*.25;
        $("#spoon").text(spoon).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:text[name="fork-143"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var fork = fork*.5;
        $("#fork").text(fork).trigger('change');
    });



    $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
        var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
            return acc + +val.textContent   ;
        }, 0);
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
<div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: drinks</h2>
<div class="drinks-123-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Coke" /> Coke
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Water" /> Water
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="No drinks-123" /> No drinks-123
</div>

<h2>Question 3: extras</h2>
<div class="drinks-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Rice" /> Rice
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoon?</h2>
<div class="spoon-wrapper">
    <textarea name="spoon-112" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra fork?</h2>
<div class="fork-wrapper">
    <input name="fork-143" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="price-wrapper">
    <b>meal:</b> <span id="meal"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>drinks:</b> <span id="drinks"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>extras:</b> <span id="extras"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>spoon:</b> <span id="spoon"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>fork:</b> <span id="fork"></span>
</div>

<div class="total-wrapper">
    <h3>
        <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You will struggle with this to a degree as change is ok for some inputs but not others - so, to try to capture radio input vs e.g. textarea input is a challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$('.meal-wrapper :input').change()` ?

And, just a suggestion, you could have used switch case for input elements value.

Comment: i havent tried yet i will .. also about your suggestion i was gonna ask on a separate thread :) i was thinking of array havent thought of switch case.. i'm really noob :(

Comment: Okay, just try this and revert back. No problem, we all are learning here. People here are too good, they will give you amazing ways to do things differently and in a better way, that we never even thought of.

Comment: its working on radio inputs but not on textarea and input type text sad thought it was all good

Comment: It must work on all input elements. The purpose of using `:input` selector was to select all input elements under `.meal-wrapper` element. 
NOTE: `change` events are differently handled for textarea and input type text elements. For such element, when you focus out of it, event listeners will check whether its value was changed (i.e. value before focus in and after focus out), and then triggers the `change` event only in case its value is changed.

Comment: my script is working perfectly without changing any codes i just want to make my life easier lol but its not as easy as i think so maybe i'll just wait for another solution thanks :D

Comment: hey guess what :D i removed the colon sign and it worked on textarea and in input text .. cool ^_^

Comment: But removing `colon` will not work on `textarea`. Just test that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener on your `class` name and trigger when `change`. Then in callback retrieve checked value.

```
$('.meal-wrapper :input').on("change", function(){
    var meal = $('.meal-wrapper :radio:checked').val();
    // or, $(this).find(:radio:checked).val(); 

   ...
   ...   

});

$(".drinks-123-wrapper :input").on("change", function(){
  var drinks = $(".drinks-123-wrapper :radio:checked").val();
  // or, $(this).find(:radio:checked).val();
  ...
  ...
});
```

Comment: tried applying it but doesnt work maybe because of my conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

ok if i understand correct you either want to access an element when its parent body/div clicked/changed.
or vise-versa means on click of your input radio-btn you want access its parent (drinks-wrapper).
if it is then yes there are many ways in jquery to do this means accessing child as wall as parent both
here is some code

for accessing any child

```
$("#parent").click(function(){        //#parent = id or class of your parent div which you will click
$(this).find("#child_id/childclass")  //#child_id/childclass= id or class of element you want to access.val()                                
})
```

in your case it would be

```
$(".drinks-wrapper").click(function(){
$(this).find('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').attr("checked")
})
//this will return you whether the meal-356 radio checked or not
```

and if you want access parents (vice-versa)
then

```
<script>
    <div class="grandfather" value="pawan chand">

        <div class="father">
            <div class="son">
                <div class="grandson">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    $(".grandson").click(function(){
var grandfather = $(this).parents(".grandfather").val();  // grandfather = pawan chand
    })
</script>
```

similarly there is a closest() function which only allow to access one level up like grandson only access son but with parents() you can access to its one level to nth level